# how can I get score from redis sorted set by rank?

Tags: redis

I have a sorted set in redis and I want to get score for 3rd element, for example.

```
redis> ZADD myzset 1 "one"
redis> ZADD myzset 2 "two"
redis> ZADD myzset 3 "three"
redis> ZADD myzset 4 "four"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ZRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) is just for that. You can choose index with point or range.

```
ZRANGE myzset 2 2 WITHSCORES
```